# Adding the correct information to a new sheet

Tags: c#

I have a little problem adding data to a new list.

This is how my DailyRoutine class looks

```
 public class DailyRoutine
    {
        public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
        public List<DateTime> G { get; set; } 
        public List<DateTime> B { get; set; } 
        public List<DateTime> P { get; set; } 
        public List<DateTime> E { get; set; } 
    }
```

Specifically, I've been returning the Dailies List for a whole week here, and for each day I get certain blocks.
this is how the data obtained looks like
[image]

I then sort that same data by day of the week because I need the data for that day.

```
 DailyRoutine dailyRoutine = dailyRoutines.SingleOrDefault(x => x.DayOfWeek == dayOfWeek);
```

this is what the same data looks like:

```
    G   1899-12-30 07:00:00.000
    B   1899-12-30 08:30:00.000
    G   1899-12-30 11:30:00.000
    B   1899-12-30 13:30:00.000
    P   1899-12-30 17:00:00.000
    G   1899-12-30 18:00:00.000
    E   1899-12-30 19:00:00.000
```

this is my list i want to fill up with data:

```
 private class Block
        {
            public DateTime Start { get; set; }
            public DateTime End { get; set; }
        }
```

this is my current code, with which I insert data into the list, but I would like to define before insertion, that the start be a position B greater than the first G, and at the end of the block list, contain B and G with values:

```
  List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>();
            for (int i = 0; i < dailyRoutine.B.Count; i++)
            {
                blocks.Add(new Block()
                {
                    Start = dailyRoutine.B[i],
                    End = dailyRoutine.G[i]
                });
            }
```

the end data should be like this

```
start =  B   {1899-12-30 08:30:00.000, 1899-12-30 13:30:00.000}
end=    G {1899-12-30 11:30:00.000, 1899-12-30 18:00:00.000}
```

is currently changing positions, and my result in the Blocks list is this:

```
start =  B   {1899-12-30 08:30:00.000, 12/30/1899 1:30:00}
end=    G {12/30/1899 7:00:00, 12/30/1899 11:30:00 }
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: @KieranDevlin I just tried to clarify everything in detail, the problem is that my data is incorrectly added to the list, I want to get this information in the list:start =  B   {1899-12-30 08:30:00.000, 1899-12-30 13:30:00.000}
end=    G {1899-12-30 11:30:00.000, 1899-12-30 18:00:00.000}.
for loop inserts positions for me only the first two which are irregular.

Comment: So if im understanding correctly, the start date time of the object you're trying to add, has an incorrect format from what you expect? If this is the case, DateTime doesn't inherently have a format. Where are you seeing an incorrect output? i.e debug window etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want the end of the first block to be the second `G` rather than the first, if so you could achieve this by accessing the index of the list one greater than `i`.
so:

```
List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>();
//Also need to check the index isn't going to be greater than the count of G
for (int i = 0; i < dailyRoutine.B.Count && i + 1 < dailyRoutine.G.Count; i++)
{
    blocks.Add(new Block()
    {
        Start = dailyRoutine.B[i],
        End = dailyRoutine.G[i + 1] //i + 1 will be the second instance when i is the first
    });
}
```

Alternatively, if you only want it to happen when the first `G` occurs before the first `B` you can do it with a conditional assignment of a second index within the `for` loop:

```
List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>();
//If either of your lists is empty, this avoids an IndexOutOfRange exception
if (dailyRoutine.B.Count > 0 && dailyRoutine.G.Count > 0)
{
    //Also need to check the index isn't going to be greater than the count of G
    for (int i = 0, j = dailyRoutine.B[0] > dailyRoutine.G[0] ? 1 : 0; i < dailyRoutine.B.Count && j < dailyRoutine.G.Count; i++, j++)
    {
        blocks.Add(new Block()
        {
            Start = dailyRoutine.B[i],
            End = dailyRoutine.G[j] //note this is 'j' not 'i'
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: suggestion alternative for loops helped me, it's a solution to my problem, really great! i didn't know i could expand for a loop like this .. thanks a lot!

Comment: i just get this error sometimes, how can i omit this error not occurring?
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "The index was out of range, it can not be negative and less than the collection.
Parameter name: index "

Comment: @Michael I've updated the code snippet to address this. Error most likely occurred during assignment of `j` when either `dailyRoutine.B` or `dailyRoutine.G` was empty.